# Does MVVM Cross Work with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cross-platform, windows-phone, mvvmcross

Would like to make a cross-platform app supporting WinPhone 7.5 and later, plus Android and IOS if possible, using VS 2010 Professional. MVVMCross looked like a good choice but I can't find any information on whether it works with VS2010 or only VS2012.

Apologies if this information is in plain sight somewhere; maybe the answer will make it show up on Google more easily for the next guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current release it should work - but you will need to make sure you have the latest PCL and nuget plugins installed.

In the near future, Microsoft seem to be pushing hard to prevent WP7.x development - they are removing WP7.x support from VS2013 so MvvmCross will most likely have to switch to WP8-only support - see http://slodge.blogspot.ca/2013/07/mvvmcross-wp7-tombstoned.html

Comment: Thanks, Stuart--I appreciate the heads-up about WP7 as well--yikes!